# How can I get an object "key" from the value? Is there something like array_search for objects?

Tags: php, arrays, object, key

I have a class like so:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [items] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 234
            [2] => 345
            [3] => 456
        )
    )
)
```

Let's call the above object `$foo`.

Let's say `$v = 234`.  Given `$foo` and `$v`, how can I return the "key" `1`?

If `$foo->items` was an array I would simply do `$key = array_search($v,$foo->items);`.  But this doesn't work in an object.

How can I find the key for `$v` without looping through the object in some `foreach`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `get_object_vars` and search through the array returned.

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Here's an example of how to search through the array returned for a key:

```
<?php
$foo = NULL;
$foo->id = 1;
$foo->items = array(123, 234, 345, 456);
$foo_array = get_object_vars($foo);
print_r($foo_array);

foreach ($foo_array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 1) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 234
            [2] => 345
            [3] => 456
        )

)
id
```

**CodePad**: http://codepad.org/in4w94nG

Comment: But $foo->items isn't an array.  It just looks like an array.  It's an object.  I'm having a hard time making this work.

Comment: Ah, I got it. `$key = array_search($v, get_object_vars($foo->items));`  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As you have shown in your example, you're dealing with `stdClass` object(s). Those are quite similar to arrays and with PHP you can easily convert between those two with something called *casting*:

```
$object = $foo->items;
$key = array_search($v, (array)$object);
                        ^^^^^^^--- cast to array
```

As this little example shows (I just used the `$object` variable to make the cast more visible, you normally can write it as one-liner), the *cast from object to array* does allow you to use the known function (`array_search`) on the object.

Because arrays and stdClass objects in PHP are so similar, this works in both directions:

```
$array  = ['property' => 'value'];
$object = (object)$array;
echo $object->property; # value
```

This also works with other types in PHP, so probably apart from your concrete problem, something worth to read about: [Type Juggling<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), but take care, that in PHP this has many special rules. But between array and objects, it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: This is simpler and cleaner than the solution that is marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

`$key = array_search($v, get_object_vars($foo->items));`

edit: try [this](http://codepad.org/EC36tThT)

Comment: array_keys won't work because $foo->items is not an array.  It's an object.

Comment: Yes, that works.  See my comment on the answer above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519115/how-can-i-get-an-object-key-from-the-value-is-there-something-like-array-sear#comment16852444_12519128